# Chance of something occuring multiple times

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

How do I calculate the chance that some event, that has $p\%$ chance of occurring per observation, will occur **at least** $k$ times over $n$ observations?

Comment: Binomial distribution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express $p$ as a decimal, for example if $p=50\%$ write $p=0.5$ and then the probability you want is equal to $$\sum_{j=k}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}p^j(1-p)^{n-j}$$ This is an instance (or application) of the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

---

Formally, if you denote with $N$ the number of occurrences of the event in $n$ observations, the $N$ is binomially distributed with parameters $p$ (expressed as a decimal) and $n$ and you want to calculate the probability $$P(N\ge k)$$ If you have a tool (like excel) that can calculate *cumulative probabilities* i.e. probabilities of the form $P(N\le x)$ then you can write $$P(N\ge k)=1-P(N\le k-1)=1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\dbinom{n}{j}p^j(1-p)^{n-j}$$